# Timesheetstaff - Function time difference in PHP

Tags: php

I have written a PHP code to match date and time which matches date but i am not able to match time. Have 2 Tables - Tbl_Staff_Master, TimeSheet.

```
$_GET['Task_DT'] - datetime.
```

**Example Task_DT= "07/17/2015 20:35:00"**

Here is my code.

```
 function timesheetstaff(){ 
        $result = '';               
        if(!empty($_GET)){                                  
            $taskdt = strtotime($_GET['Task_DT']);
            $tdate = date('Y-m-d',$taskdt);
            $ttime = date('H:i:s',$taskdt);                 
            //echo $tdate." ".$ttime;
            //exit(0);
            $useinfo = array();
            $eventData = $this->ez_db->get_results("SELECT distinct sm.*,ts.FD,ts.TD,ts.FT,ts.TT FROM Tbl_Staff_Master sm, TimeSheet ts WHERE sm.SCId = ts.SCId and sm.Is_Deleted='0'");
            foreach($eventData as $row)
            {
                if($row->FD >=$tdate && $row->TD <=$tdate) && ($row->FT >=$ttime && $row->TT <=$ttime))                 
                {               
                    $useinfo['SCId'] = $row->SCId;
                    $useinfo['First_Name'] = $row->First_Name;
                    $useinfo['Last_Name'] = $row->Last_Name;
                }   
            }                   
            echo '{"status":true,"items":'.json_encode($useinfo).'}'; exit(0);  
        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid URL";exit;        
        }
        }
```

**SQL Table Schema**

```
-- Table structure for table `Tbl_Staff_Master`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tbl_Staff_Master` (
  `SCId` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `First_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Contact_No` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Email_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `SC_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Is_Deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Action` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LoginSt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Token` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SCId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=211 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TimeSheet` (
  `TSId` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SCId` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `FD` date NOT NULL,
  `TD` date NOT NULL,
  `FT` time NOT NULL,
  `TT` time NOT NULL,
  `TS_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TSId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=176 ;
```

**Some Data in Table**

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `Tbl_Staff_Master`
--

INSERT INTO `Tbl_Staff_Master` (`SCId`, `Cid`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `City`, `Address`, `Contact_No`, `Email_ID`, `Password`, `SC_DT`, `Status`, `Is_Deleted`, `Action`, `LoginSt`, `Token`) VALUES
(210, 25, 'Asss', 'H', 'B', 'H', '45tyi', 'hjhg', 'P@ssword123', '2015-07-16 09:27:58', 0, 0, 0, 0, '4ab21e845cb9f82f4c5beefd86fadf3989c291c0c761c74');


--
-- Dumping data for table `TimeSheet`
--

INSERT INTO `TimeSheet` (`TSId`, `SCId`, `FD`, `TD`, `FT`, `TT`, `TS_DT`) VALUES
(174, 184, '2015-07-17', '2015-07-17', '19:35:00', '20:35:00', '2015-07-14 13:05:43'),
(175, 184, '2015-07-18', '2015-07-18', '21:43:00', '22:43:00', '2015-07-14 13:13:54'),
(173, 184, '2015-07-19', '2015-07-19', '19:15:00', '20:15:00', '2015-07-14 12:46:20');
```

Comment: what is in $_GET['Task_DT']? What did **not** work for you?

Comment: @donald123  $_GET['Task_DT'] is the datetime that is inputted by the user in a form. Its Specific Task Date & Time like
Task_DT=07/17/2015 20:35:00

Comment: **what** is the string, the content ... ?

Comment: Its Specific Task Date & Time like Task_DT=07/17/2015 20:35:00